# Как послать файл и JSON в одном POST-запросе используя тестовый клиент Flask-a?

Tags: python, flask

Привет,

В англоязычной версии SO есть вопрос [Using Python Requests to send file and JSON in single request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642040/using-python-requests-to-send-file-and-json-in-single-request). Мне нужно тоже самое, но только лишь с использованием тествого клиента от Flask. Под тестовым клиентом понимаю результат вызова test_client() от инстанса Flask-а.

Возможно ли это?

На всякий случай, тестовый клиент получаю так:

```
def create_app(configName='default'):
    result = Flask(__name__)
    result.config.from_object(config[configName])

# more lines

  def setUp(self):
    self.app = create_app(configName='testing')
    self.app_ctx = self.app.app_context()
    self.app_ctx.push()
    db.create_all()
    self.client = self.app.test_client()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
fp = StringIO('my file contents')
metadata = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
client.post(
    '/upload'
    data = {
        'file': (fp, 'test.txt'),
        'data': json.dumps(metadata),
    }
)
```

Файл будет доступен как `request.files['file']`, а данные как `request.form['data']`.

Comment: Спасибо. Вопросы. 1. Сам файл будет зачитываться в память порциями или же сразу целиком? 2. Почему Вы указали файл в аргументе 'file' словаря 'data' ? Есть же вроде аргумент 'files' метода post ...

Comment: 1. Понятия не имею. Предполагаю, что целиком, так как в тестовом клиенте нет смысла заморачиваться.

Comment: 2. Нет, у метода `post` нет аргумента `files`. Тестовый клиент построен на `werkzeug.test.EnvironBuilder`. Поглядите описание параметра `data` (http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/test/#werkzeug.test.EnvironBuilder), передавать нужно именно в нем, а вот как называть, не важно, главное, строка это или файловый объект.

Comment: Спасибо. То что надо. Добился результата. Посланный по Вашему совету файл в тестовом клиенте, мой веб-сервис принял ;)

Comment: @sys_dev, очень рад, что смог помочь :)